# MacBook abruptly turn off

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a MacBook Model A1278. After a replacement of the battery in a moment of low charge (like 5-7%) the laptop is abruptly shutting down. As far as I remember it should be like a "sleep mode" or something like that.

Additionally, in a process of normal shutting down that I do by myself with any percent of charge, I hear some clicking sounds from the HDD that means that the HDD was turned off incorrectly (in a moment when read head doesn't stop in a parking zone).

For the first try of repair I did reset of PRAM and SMC but it doesn't help. As a result, either PRAM or SMC didn't reset (how I can check it?) or there is something else. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** Thank you everyone for attention! So here is more information:

1. I Have A1278 Mid-2012 model.
2. I've using macOS 10.12.2
3. After the command `syslog | grep shutdown` I've got the result in only one line

   > NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See
   >   log(1) for more information.
4. I'm trying to fix the abrupt shutdown. There should be a something like sleep/hibernation mode when the battery charge is lower 5% instead
5. I've tried to calibrate battery with no luck

Comment: The A1278 is a 13" MBP that goes from 2009-2013; which one do you ***specifically*** have?  What OS are you using?  What is the shutdown cause in your syslog?   Issue the command `syslog | grep shutdown` and **edit your question** to update it with the new info.  What specifically are you attempting to fix?  The abrupt shutdown or the sleep/hibernation mode?

Comment: Did you install the battery? One thing to try (if you haven't yet), is to calibrate the battery. Easy to follow instructional videos can be found on sites like Other World Computing.

Comment: That error message from `syslog` indicates that you're on 10.12 (Sierra) or later.  This is why it's ***important to include your OS and Mac model when asking questions.***  Try the command `log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "shutdown"' --style syslog --info`

Comment: @Allan thank you! The logs are available here: http://pastebin.com/bsjiEbME

Answer (score 2):

How did you reset the SMC?

It's not clear exactly what model of MacBook you have, but the process for resetting the SMC can differ. I have included two sets of instructions below that could apply to you - select the one that matches your *Battery* type.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, and MacBooks where you can’t remove the battery on your own (i.e. it's a built-in battery), here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBooks etc that you can remove the battery from, here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. **Disconnect** the MagSafe plug (power cable) from the computer
3. Remove the battery
4. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> for 5 seconds and release
5. Put the battery back in
6. Reconnect the MagSafe cord (or power cable)
7. Turn your computer back on with the power button

Comment: Thank you! I did excatly the same thing. The reciepts of resetting PRAM and SMD I've got from the Apple Knowledge Database (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is something with the battery:
if it is not an original battery, replace it with an original Apple battery, the rest is crap, although Newertech batteries are not too bad.
If it is a real Apple battery, you may have used it too harshly (never let it come empty say, charge when 20% or higher):
Could you give the Cycle Count and the Battery condition please (Applications->Utilities->SystemInformation->Power, then on the right side you read these)
LexS

Comment: I've tried two absolutely different batteries: original and not. Both have the cycle count less than 30. Same problem.